# Webkit Animation and transform

Tags: css, animation, webkit, transform, css-animations

I currently have a problem with the implementation of a loader CSS on Chrome.

I post the jsFiddle.

Nothing happens in Chrome but it works fine on Mozilla.

Thank you for your help

http://jsfiddle.net/Tpf9X/

HTML :

```
<div class="ball"></div>
<div class="ball1"></div>
```

CSS

```
  .ball {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,183,229,0.9);
    opacity: .9;
    border-top: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-left: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 35px #2187e7;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -moz-animation: spin .5s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spin .5s infinite linear;
}

.ball1 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,183,229,0.9);
    opacity: .9;
    border-top: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-left: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #2187e7;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    -moz-animation: spinoff .5s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spinoff .5s infinite linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    };
}

@-moz-keyframes spinoff {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    };
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    };
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinoff {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove semi-colons after braces and it will work

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tpf9X/1/)

```
100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
}; /* <--- Invalid, need to get rid of those */
```

BTW, nice animation.

Complete Code

```
.ball {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,183,229,0.9);
    opacity: .9;
    border-top: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-left: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 35px #2187e7;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -moz-animation: spin .5s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spin .5s infinite linear;
}

.ball1 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,183,229,0.9);
    opacity: .9;
    border-top: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-left: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #2187e7;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    -moz-animation: spinoff .5s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spinoff .5s infinite linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes spinoff {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinoff {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```